# Should I go with 'complex problems' or 'tricky problems' in my cover letter?

Tags: cover-letter

I writing a cover letter and I am not sure what it is more appropriate to say - if complex problems or tricky problems.

The whole sentence is:

```
I have strong analytical skills, which enable me to tackle complex problems.
```

Which one do you believe to be a better fit?

Comment: Voting to close, as answers will be primarily opinion-based. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Comment: Definitely run it through a grammar checker.

Comment: I will, Aaron, especially because I am not a native English speaker so I defo need to run it thru a grammar checker.

Comment: Using "which" is not a good idea in any sentence

Comment: Really? Good to know. And I thought the only weirdness in another sentence I wrote ('[...] I am constantly studying software architecture and design, which are two topics I am very much interested in.') was the 'in' in the end of the sentence. Got to find a way to get rid of that 'which' too.

Comment: Which change to that

Comment: "I am not a native English speaker so I *defo* need to run it thru a grammar checker" I'd be losing this one too :)

Comment: A general piece of advice for selling yourself like this: **show, don't tell.** Don't explain that you can do something, explain how and when you actually did something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to you that the set of employers who would be thrilled to know you can solve complex problems, but not even interview you because you used the phrase "tricky problems" in your cover letter is zero. In any event it is far smaller than the set of employers who will overlook "which enables to" - an awkward construct that would probably be improved by putting "me" after "enables" and fixing "enables" to "enable" since it is your plural skills that are enabling you to tackle the problems under discussion.

You are overthinking this in the worst possible way. Relax and write a letter that describes yourself, then if you can, have a native English speaker look it over for awkward constructs. If you don't have such a person a grammar checker will help somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your input Kate. I am not a native English speaker so I couldn't really tell by myself if the word 'tricky' sounded too informal. BTW thanks for pointing out my grammar mistake. I will get it fixed as you suggested.

Comment: Cover letters can be informal. Maybe not slangy but a little casual. Heck, say "tricky and complex" if you like. Your energy is going into details that are too small. I know it feels like you have to get this perfect to be hired, but that's just not how it works.

Comment: @Kate Are you sure that "enable" should be changed to "enable"? To me, "which" refers to the preceding phrase (because of the comma). In this sense, "which" refers to a singular fact (the posession of skills), so I think that the verb should be singular as well.

Comment: would you write "my skills enable me to solve" or "my skills enables me to solve" ? Sticking the "which" in there changes nothing - it refers to your skills. But if you're unsure, split the sentence. "I have strong analytical skills. This enables me to..."